# C# method call error

Tags: c#, methods

Yes, I'm new to C#, but I'm a decent Java developer. OK, I've got a project in Visual Studio with a `program.cs` file and a `Class.cs` file. All I'm trying to do is make a call to the method in `Class.cs` in `Program.cs`. I have one frustrating error. The name 'mymethod' does not exist in the current context. All the other code builds fine if I comment out the method call `mymethod(parameter);` but I can't get rid of that bug. I would greatly appreciate any help.

```
 public class Class
{
     public void myMethod() 
{

class Program
{
     static void Main(string[] args)
{
```

Comment: Nobody can help you until you post some code.  Please edit your response with your code, and change your question title to reflect the specific problem you are having.

Comment: Generally these are called build or complier errors not bug code has to run to have a bug.

Comment: All these answers are so lame for a Java Developer. Because they are just imagining about the code you have written. Share your code and we'll share our ideas.

Comment: For a decent Java Dev, this should be a walk in the park.. Its the same as in Java..

Comment: Why the downvotes? Be kind to new users and just explain that he should post some code. Don't want to scare users away, do you?

Comment: sorry guys i will post my code from now on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't work?

```
public class Class
{
    public void myMethod() 
    {

    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class c = new Class();
        c.myMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry guys i will post my code from now on. The answer does work I just have to have all code in one file. Thats how I did it in Java. So I spranged my ankle on the "walk in the park" because of the use of two different files. ( the class file and the program/main() file.

Comment: @nuclearpro - keep in mind that when you have code in different files, the classes may exist in different namespaces (particularly if they are also in different folders). Be sure to check your namespaces before putting multiple classes in the same file. Also check your protection levels.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you didn't put **public** in front of the method in question.

Comment: I can't believe this would be true unless their definition of decent Java developer is a bit flawed.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: Whilst you have a valid point, I ceased to be surprised by anything these days.

Comment: public static void myMethod(string sentence)

Comment: wow! lots of moody DEVs out there... didnt mean to bring you guys down

Comment: @nuclearpro - Wasn't being moody mate :)  It was a genuine thought, had you made it publically accessible?  With regard to your comments on other answers, you shouldn't need to throw all your code in to a single file for it to work.  Unless a class is small and utilitarian, it gets its own file.

Comment: yes it seems that everything is in order except main won't recognize my method name from another class. Every things public I'm not trying to encapsulate just build. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe you didn't mark the method as static?

Comment: The answer does work I just have to have all code in one file. Thats how I did it in Java. So I spranged my ankle on the "walk in the park" because of the use of two different files. ( the class file and the program/main() file.  Good god my first question and I'm getting pounded!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably calling the method without creating an object first:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
    }
}

MyClass.MyMethod();
```

You should create an instance first:

```
var obj = new MyClass();
obj.MyMethod();
```